# Magento2.3: How to remove others in general at registration form?

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, phtml, registration, account

In account registration form, we have a gender field, on that there are three options as Male, Female and Others. I want to remove Others in registration form.

How can I remove that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this file

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/gender.phtml

in your custom theme here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/widget/gender.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender $block */
?>
<div class="field gender<?= $block->isRequired() ? ' required' : ''?>">
    <label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('gender')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('gender')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('gender')) ?>" name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('gender')) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('gender')) ?>"<?php if ($block->isRequired()) : ?> class="validate-select" data-validate="{required:true}"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php $options = $block->getGenderOptions(); ?>
            <?php $value = $block->getGender(); ?>
            <?php foreach ($options as $option) : ?>
                <?php if($option->getValue() != 3): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($option->getValue()) ?>"<?= ($option->getValue() == $value) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($option->getLabel())) ?></option>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Just want to know, can I remove the value "others" from gender attribute? Is that work?

Comment: Yes, @Siva, If you'll remove that attribute value that also work.

Comment: @Siva, updated my answer.

Comment: Tried with remove the attribute value and its working great. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @Siva

Comment: One question here, Before I remove the attribute value via database, I have tried in removing it from admin but I couldn't. Is we can't remove it from admin?

Comment: @Siva, in community version we can see only product attributes so we need to remove value from database.

Comment: Yes, you're right we don't have customer attributes in community version. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Create a After plugin for `vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Widget/Gender.php` class `getGenderOptions` method and remove `**Others**` option from your result data.